# Do stateless Green Card holders need schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, stateless-persons

I am from the former soviet union, and I have just got my green card after a few years ago.

I am still stateless and have applied for a refugee travel document which may or may not come through.

My question is, if I get my Refugee Travel Document, do I still need a schengen visa?

I just need to go to Germany for about a week for training for my job.

That's all.

Comment: Do former Soviet union countries not issue new passports ?

Comment: @blackbird57 As most countries, former Soviet union countries usually only issue passports to their own citizens. If the OP is stateless, he can't simply go to a former Soviet consulate and expect to be issued a passport.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo but I imagine they must have some provision where if you were born in a specific soviet republic you're entitled to something today ? I met a woman who was born in Yugoslavia but had a Croatian passport

Comment: @blackbird57: After the Soviet Union broke up, not entirely amicably, each of the resulting states made up their own rules about who they would consider their citizens. It seems quite conceivable that someone can have slipped through the cracks and end up not recognized by _any_ of the successor states -- especially if they were living outside the USSR at the time of the breakup.

Comment: @blackbird57 Not necessarily. Even if it worked out for most Ex-Soviet citizens, the former Soviet countries now have so different nationality laws, that many persons fell out of the system and did not have a possibility to obtain a new citizenship. Assume that A and B are two former Soviet countries, you are ethnic A, but were resident in B. If after the Soviet breakup, A award citizenship based on residency and B award citizenship based on ethnicity, you would not get citizenship of either country.